# Need direction for solving integral

Tags: integration

> Evaluate: $$\int \frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x +4}dx.$$

I tried to this things:

**First**

$$\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) = t$$

$$dx = \frac{2~dt}{1+t^2}$$

$$\sin x= \frac{2t}{1+t^2}$$

$$\cos x= \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$

Tried also but this is same thing?

$$\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) = t$$

There I don't have to place $2$ left to integral ( same thing )

**Second**

I tried trigonometric transformations like

$$\sin^2x \equiv 1-\cos^2x$$

$$\int \frac{1-\cos^2x}{\cos^2x +4}dx$$
$$-1\cdot \int \frac{\cos^2x-1}{\cos^2x +4}~dx$$
$$-1\cdot \int \frac{\cos^2x+4-5}{\cos^2x +4}~dx$$

But I get stucked in this part
$$5\int \frac{1}{\cos^2x +4}dx.$$

And mix something from first step

**Third**

I tried to divide everything with $\sin^2x$, but didn't succeed to solve + mix something from first step

**Can anyone give me direction how to solve this?**

**sorry, for late update....**

My goal is to complete this task without trigonometry function sec

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why the apprehension about using $\sec$?

Comment: We didn't do tasks on faculty with sec, I didn't know it exist, so it is little wierd for me to use it

Answer (score 0):

HINT:
$$\frac{x^2}{5-x^2}=-\frac{-x^2+5-5}{5-x^2}=-1+\frac{5}{5-x^2}=-1+\frac{A}{\sqrt{5}-x}+\frac{B}{\sqrt{5}+x}\\A(\sqrt{5}+x)+B(\sqrt{5}-x)=5$$
Now when you solve for $A,B$ instead of $x$ plug in $\sin(x)$ [$\cos^2x+4=5-\sin^2 x$]

Comment: I will update in 1-2 min my second try in my original post, to see if what u are saying is that

Comment: I tried to plug 5-sin^2x but don't know later how when we looking for deegres etc sinx°, do u understand me?

Answer (score 0):

substituting $t=\tan x$, with $dx=\frac{dt}{1+t^2}$ gives $$\int\frac{t^2}{(5+4t^2)(1+t^2)}dt=\int\frac{5}{5+4t^2}-\frac{1}{1+t^2}dt$$

So you end up with $$\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\arctan\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\tan x\right)-x+c$$

Comment: Tried, In that case I dont have to place 2 left from integral... I updated second part in my post

Comment: Please see my edited answer

Comment: Don't understand how u get this t^2/(5+4t^2) ?

Comment: Divide every term by $\cos^2x$ and use $1+\tan^2x=\sec^2x$

Comment: Can u do it without sec?

Comment: Yes if you write $\frac{1}{\cos x}$ instead

Answer (score 0):

> $$\int \frac{1}{\cos^2x +4}dx$$

Divide top and bottom of integrand by $\cos^2 x$,

$$=\int \frac{\sec^2 x}{1+4\sec^2 x} dx $$

Now use $\tan^2 x+1=\sec^2 x$ to get,

$$=\int \frac{\sec^2 x}{1+4(\tan^2 x+1)} dx$$

$$=\int \frac{\sec^2 x}{5+4 \tan^2 x} dx$$

Let $u=\tan x$.

$$=\int \frac{1}{5+4u^2} du$$

$$=\frac{1}{5} \int \frac{1}{1+\frac{4}{5}u^2} du$$

$$=\frac{1}{5} \int \frac{1}{1+(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}u)^2} du$$

$$=\frac{1}{5} \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2} \int \frac{\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}}{1+(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}u)^2} du$$

I think you can deal with this.

Comment: Thanks, I'm waiting for answer without sec, that I can understand ( I'm waiting on David Quinn response, on his answer ) , but also this is great

Comment: You're welcome, glad you found it helpful :)